# Replace Lessthan and character with Lessthan space and character in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my text box, i should find (`<LessThan Symobl>` `<character>`) and replace with (`<LessThan Symbol <space> <character>`)

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
abc<xyz abc <abc
```

**output:**

```
abc< xyz abc < abc
```

---

From a string, i should find (**[LessThanSymbol]**  **[character]**) and replace with (**[LessThanSymbol] [space] [Character]** ) in javascript

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the desired result...

Comment: Re write the question please!

Comment: I have rewritten the question again below.   I should probably need some regular expression that finds lessthan symbol followed by a character and replace with lessthan symbol followed by space followed by character.

Comment: There is an edit button under the question.  Do not rewrite the question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to find all `<` character that are followed by a non-space character, and insert a space:

```
s = s.replace(/<([^ ])/g, '< $1');
```

Comment: It is working fine. But, it is also inserting space if there is new line character after < character. I should not insert space if there is new line character after <

Comment: @SKumar: You can use `\S` instead of `[^ ]` to match any non-whitespace character instead of any non-space character.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.replace(/<(?=\S|$)/g, "< ");
```

What this means:

- You can guess what `.replace()` does and what the `<` represents.  :-)
- `(?=...)` is a "positive look-ahead" — it means "followed by".
- `\S` matches any *non*-whitespace character (anything other than spaces, non-breaking spaces, tabs, carriage returns, and newlines).
- `$` matches the end of the string.
- `/.../g` performs a global search/replace.

Using the look-ahead prevents you from having to use a capturing group (`$1`), using `\S` fixes your newline problem, and using `$` keeps you from having a similar problem if the string ends with a less-than.

```
>>> "<foo < bar <\tbaz <\rquux <\nquuux <".replace(/<(?=\S|$)/g, "< ")
"< foo < bar <\tbaz <\rquux <\nquuux <"
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found is this :

```
s = s.replace(/<(?!\s)(?!$)/g,'< ');
```

It means:

- (?!\s) - not followed by a whitespace (Negative Lookahead)
- (?!$) - not followed by the end of the string (Negative Lookahead)

---

You can also use a split() then a join() :

```
'abc<xyz abc <abc'.split('<').join('< ')
```

But there is a problem with this method : the trail character which is completed with a non necessary space.

```
'abc<xyz abc <abc<'.split('<').join('< ')
```

gives this result

```
'abc< xyz abc < abc< '
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

```
var string_variable;
string_variable = "Replace text using javascript replace function within a javascript string variable";
string_variable = string_variable.replace(/javascript/g, "js");
alert(string_variable);
```

(see: http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/replace-all-occurrences-of-string-using-javascript-replace-function.aspx)

Comment: The "/g" causes the replace to replace all occurrences... if it's possible you might already have "< x" then you can run the process and replace the "< " with "<" and then run the process to add the space back.

Comment: I do not know what letter comes after LessThan symbol. I should probably need some regular expression that finds lessthan symbol followed by a character and replace with lessthan symbol followed by space followed by character. But, I don't know how to do it

Comment: If you have "<1", do you want to replace it with "< 1" or do you just want to do this for alpha characters?

Comment: I want to do this only for alpha characters

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this.

```
s= s.replace(/<([^ \n])/g, '< $1');
```

It inserts space after lessthan for  all the occurances of lessthan followed by (nonspace and non new line)